# Get all files from folder and their infromation

Tags: c#, uwp, storage

So I created a `sample.txt` via UWP and copy/past a `sample2.pdf` and a `sample3.mp4` in the local folder of my UWP App.

So right now I have those 3 files in my folder.

Then I created a class which should save the `filename, extension, id and modifiedDate`

Now I want to create a list of this class with the information of the sample files. Example of a class Variable would be: `filename = sample, extension = .txt, id = sample, modified date = 30.10.2018 09:00`

How would I do that?

My Code so far:

```
public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
{
    Windows.Storage.StorageFolder storageFolder;
    Windows.Storage.StorageFile sampleFile;
    List<FileElements> fileInformation = new List<FileElements>();

    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        moth();
    }

    async void moth()
    {
        storageFolder =
            Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        sampleFile =
            await storageFolder.CreateFileAsync("sample.txt",
                Windows.Storage.CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
    }

    public class FileElements
    {
        public string filename { get; set; }
        public string extension { get; set; }
        public string id { get; set; }
        public string modifiedDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I tried to figure it out with the `foreach()` methode but it doesnt work

"foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type StorageFile because StorageFile does not contain a public definition for GetEnumerator"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`DirectoryInfo().GetFiles()` returns an array of `FileInfo()` which contains all information you need, so you can select from it in any way you like:

```
var result = System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(dirPath);
             dir.GetFiles().Select((x,i) => new FileElements {
                filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x.FullName),
                extension = x.Extension,
                id = i.ToString(),
                modifiedDate = x.LastWriteTime.ToString()
            });
```

**Edit (considering your comment):**

the above result is an `IEnumerable<FileElements>` that does not support indexing, but it can be used in a foreach loop. however you can convert it to FileElements[] simply by `.ToArray()` to be able to use indexing:

```
var result = System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(dirPath);
                 dir.GetFiles().Select((x,i) => new FileElements {
                    filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(x.FullName),
                    extension = x.Extension,
                    id = i.ToString(),
                    modifiedDate = x.LastWriteTime.ToString()
                }).ToArray();
```

Comment: _Path.GetFilenameWithoutExtension_ is better than that Split. (example Filename.someothertext.txt)

Comment: @Steve you are absolutely right, i edited my answer.

Comment: At this point I wonder. Does he really need a class FileElements when there is a FileInfo?

Comment: @Steve does he need FileElements, was exactly what I thought, but I thought may be he needs to save it in a specific format, make a json, ...

Comment: @AshkanMobayenKhiabani thank you so far. I have another question though. How would I get the information in result[0] ? Like for example var r = result[0] is not the right way.